# Remove fake scrollbar when menu toggled closed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am adding a fake scrollbar to my page when the fullscreen menu is opened to stop the content jumping horizontally. The fake scrollbar has solved this but it remains when the menu is closed so I now have 2 scrollbars. How do I amend my code to remove the scrollbar when the menu is toggled closed?

```
var menuButton = document.getElementById("menu-button");
menuButton.addEventListener('click', () => {

   // get width before hiding scrollbar
   let oldWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

   // toggle CSS class that sets overflow to hidden
   document.querySelector("html").classList.toggle("no-scroll");

   // get new width after hiding scrollbar
   let newWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

   // set margin-right value equal to width of the scrollbar
   let scrollbarWidth = 8;
   document.body.style.marginRight = `${scrollbarWidth}px`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For you remove scroll bar than you don't use, you can use CSS to hide the scrollbar when the class is applied.

Here is an example. it's just a test

JS:

```
document.getElementById('menu').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('menu').classList.toggle('is-open');
});

document.getElementById('menu').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('test-scrollbar').classList.toggle('is-hidden');
});
```

CSS:

```
#test-scrollbar.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
  <!-- menu content -->
  click here
</div>
<div id="test-scrollbar">
  showing
</div>
```

```js
document.getElementById('menu').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('menu').classList.toggle('is-open');
});

document.getElementById('menu').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('test-scrollbar').classList.toggle('is-hidden');
});
```

```css
#test-scrollbar.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <!-- menu content -->
  click here
</div>
<div id="test-scrollbar">
showing
</div>
```